# Mysql record truncated

Tags: php, mysql, row

Here is my scenario:

```
  some code..
  $fil = implode(", ", $fields);
  $val = implode(", ", $values);
  $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} (" . $fil . ") VALUES (" . $val . ")";
```

The $val is something like this:
`'2014-05-01', '0', '0', '222', 'a', 'b', 'c', '["53623cdc1995f.jpg","53623cdc19d36.jpg","53623cdc1a11e.jpg","53623cdc1a50d.jpg"]'`

The problem is that when the part with images of $val is longer, it is for some reason truncated to this:
`["event_id_49_image_id_535fbd9807b2e.jpg","event_id_49_image_id_535fbd9807f23.jpg","event_id_49_imag`

The row type is Longtext so there should be plenty spaces left.

Update: SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `Events` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
 `image[]` longtext COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=93 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check the size of the field in the table

Comment: LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB

Comment: Do you use by chance the GET method for $val?

Comment: I notice that the truncated value is exactly 100 characters long. This seems significant. Can you please show the result of `SHOW CREATE tablename`?

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol: I updated the question.

Comment: @ VMai: Almost all the values are from $_POST array. I serialize a names of images ($_FILE['input']['name']) and store in the $val array as a string.

Comment: Thank you, It was not a magical bug. I have to be more attentive.